How to make side shadows using RealityKit on visionOS?
How can I add shadows to the walls in this RealityView so that the walls are not looking in a way that they are merged together?
Currently I am using ShadowComponent and also IBL.


Lighting in visionOS 2.0+
RealityKit API and Reality Composer Pro 2.0 for visionOS 2.0 are capable to use 2 types of lighting fixtures (spot light and directional light) that are capable to generate horizontal and vertical shadows with blurry edges. Let's see how a miniature scene looks like in RCP 2.0 with spotlight shadows turned on.

Use this code to add a light in RealityKit USDZ scene:
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { rvc in
            let scene = try! await Entity(named: "Lighting")
            scene.position.z = -3.0
            scene.scale *= 5
            rvc.add(scene)
            
            let spotLight = SpotLight()
            spotLight.position = [-2.2, 1.2, 1]
            spotLight.orientation = .init(angle: .pi/36, axis: [0,-1,0])
            
            spotLight.light.color = .white
            spotLight.light.intensity = 700_000
            spotLight.light.innerAngleInDegrees = 45
            spotLight.light.outerAngleInDegrees = 120
            spotLight.light.attenuationRadius = 25
            
            spotLight.shadow = .init()
            spotLight.shadow?.depthBias = 0.7
            rvc.add(spotLight)
        }
    }
}

It's the same scene, but 5 times bigger. Therefore, the shadows become more blurry.



Lighting in visionOS 1.3
visionOS 1.0–1.3 does not have the ability to render self-shadows for models, which also includes the inability to generate SSAO. The only thing I can recommend for visionOS 1.3 app is to map UV textures with already drawn shadows, the same way it's implemented in rooms for the visionOS simulator. In addition, fake shadows have an important advantage: they do not consume processor resources.

Interesting, will try it! Do you think, it will be changed in the future? It is possible to do that in iOS right?

Today it's impossible to predict the logic of the guys from Cupertino. The day before yesterday, for example, Apple restricted the use of the Vision Pro camera for third-party apps. Despite the fact that iOS RealityKit has lighting fixtures, the situation with shadows there leaves much to be desired.
